# PHP & MySQL - math and array problems

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add all the values from the `grade_points` field for example `10, 12.5, 2.1` and then divide it by how many times grade points where entered into the database for example `24.6 / 3`.

I know that `$total_rating_points` is an array but I don't really know how to convert the array so I can add the total grade points and then divide it by how many times points where entered. I was hoping if someone can help me out with this problem? That I have been working on forever.

Here is the code I'm having trouble on.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT grade_points 
         FROM grades 
         JOIN articles_grades ON grades.id = articles_grades.grade_id
         WHERE articles_grades.users_articles_id = '$page'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2);

if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2)) {
        print mysqli_error($dbc);
        return;
}

$total_rating_points = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


if (!empty($total_rating_points) && !empty($total_ratings)){
    $avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
    $votes = $total_ratings;
    echo $avg . "/10  (" . $votes . " votes cast)";
} else {
    echo '(no votes cast)';
}
```

Here is the full code I'm working on.

```
function getRatingText(){
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");

    $page = '3';

    $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(users_articles_id) 
             FROM articles_grades 
             WHERE users_articles_id = '$page'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql1);

    if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1)) {
            print mysqli_error($dbc);
            return;
    }

    $total_ratings = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $sql2 = "SELECT grade_points 
             FROM grades 
             JOIN articles_grades ON grades.id = articles_grades.grade_id
             WHERE articles_grades.users_articles_id = '$page'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2);

    if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2)) {
            print mysqli_error($dbc);
            return;
    }

    $total_rating_points = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


    if (!empty($total_rating_points) && !empty($total_ratings)){
        $avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
        $votes = $total_ratings;
        echo $avg . "/10  (" . $votes . " votes cast)";
    } else {
        echo '(no votes cast)';
    }
}
```

Comment: And by the way, despite clearly being a new programmer, this was an excellently formatted question for the site. Good style.

Comment: formatting makes code easier to read something I learned from html and css :)

Comment: Just as a side note, instead of using `if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2)) {`, try `if(!$result) {`. It will save you a DB request and speed up your code a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

To start off, you need to grab ALL of the values from your query. PHP's library only returns results *one row at a time* so you need to loop over it and continue to get results until you have them all. So do this:

```
$resource = mysqli_query($statement);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($resource))
{
    $total_results_points[] = $result[0];
}
```

From there, summing and averaging the array in PHP should be fairly simple:

```
$average = array_sum($total_rating_points) / count($total_rating_points)
```

In a nutshell, the array_sum() function returns all the elements in an array added together. The count() function tells you how many elements are in the array. So using the two, you can obtain the mean of the array quite easily.

Comment: where do I put this in my code because I tried the `array_sum()` function and couldn't get it to work right.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, as I usually fetch_assoc on my SQL returns, but I think you're only getting one row at a time. In other words, you need to constantly loop over your MySQL results, adding each returned value to the array, and stopping when the returned value is NULL. But I might be wrong-- vardump($yourArray) and see if it's returning all the values of the query at once, or just the first one.

Comment: Updated the question to detail these steps... oh, whoops the formatting's all wrong *fixes that*

Comment: Note that in PHP, the while statement will exit on several conditions, including empty strings, NULL, and 0. In this case, it's testing whatever gets stored in $result, since the assignment operator returns the result in addition to actually performing the assignment. So effectively, your while loop will break when $result contains NULL, indicating the end of the query results. (note that if the query contains only a field with a 0 for example, it will still work because $result is an Array(), and not the value 0.)

Answer (score 0):

When you're confused about what's in an array you can use

```
print_r($total_rating_points);
```

To see what's in the array.

EDIT: Responding to comment

You have to use a while.  mysqli_fetch_array retrieves a row, not all rows.  So something like this would be in order:

```
$total_rating_points = array(); 
while ($rating_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $total_rating_points[] = $rating_row[0]; //0 might be the wrong index depending on the actual query.
}

print_r($total_rating_points);
```

You can then use array functions like sum and count as mentioned in some of the other solutions.

Comment: I did this but for some reason it only displays the first value and not the other two values.

Comment: See edits for explanation of why it's only showing you the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just go:

```
SELECT AVG(grade_points) 
     FROM grades 
     JOIN articles_grades ON grades.id = articles_grades.grade_id
     WHERE articles_grades.users_articles_id = '$page'
```

One call to mysql_fetch_array will return the only row returned by this statement, an array with one element, there's your average.